# Problems with alertdialog and fragment activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I know a similar question has been posted before but I think this is a different scenario. 
I am having problem with the show function as I am unable to get getSupportFragmentManager(). I cannot extend FragmentActivity in the MainActivity as I have already extended MapActivity (it is a map based application).

A button on the main page brings up this alert dialog and I keep getting

```
The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not 
applicable for        
the arguments (FragmentManager, String)
```

What work around can I get for this ? I followed the developer guide from google and they have extended FragmentActivity. I think I am missing something here.

It would be great if someone can help me out.

Update: I tried out with just a plain example and extended FragmentActivity and it worked. Apparently, FragmentActivity needs to be extended for this to work (unless if someone can give a workaround). 
Is there a way to extend FragmentActivity and MapActivity ?

Comment: This might be useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using android maps v1 (i know i need to shift) but I was hoping to push this off without having to shift to the new api now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit:

> The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not 
>   applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

looks to me like a clash between the "native" fragment support of Honeycomb and the "compatibility" fragment support in the support-v4 library. Check your imports, you're probably passing a [`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) into a method that takes a [`android.app.FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html), or vice versa.

Comment: Well, I have imported android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment for DialogFragment and I believe that is what is required ?

Comment: You have to use either everything from the support package or everything from Honeycomb-or-later. You can't mix and match. Check out the link that @ninetwozero commented below your question. That's probably what you need.

Comment: I just tried out a new project with fragmentactivity extended and it worked, apparently FragmentActivity needs to be extended for the dialog to pop, is there a way I can extend both FragmentActivity and MapActivity ?

Comment: No, but you can extend MapFragment and host it in a FragmentActivity.